# how to show images from mysql database correctly in php mvc?

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, model-view-controller

when I use this code below in a single php file, it works, but when I use it into mvc, it doesn't work. can someone tell me where is the problem? thank you vere much to everybody.

I receive this text instead the image:

�PNG  IHDRd}T;�sRGB���gAMA���a  pHYs���+k�IDATx^ͽxVW5ܩN;ҙN]h�]��%��]�C�R�P�@q �B���q���_���!Pڙv����gNq5��*y�j���Y�²�W�#��*�1���(��FQy�/D��TR/�������    �TN�/�B ([B�+���Tq����J<�,����?�@rli5��5��<*�W40j����*%uy��"�����*��iF2~ܱ�;6ŦY#pd�d[7'֍�����y�hY1 �V��鵣pj�H�h[3������8���6O����c����5o0�����S{`��.J

thanks.

Comment: <?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "db";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$conexao = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
$db=mysql_select_db("db",$conexao); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT photo FROM table WHERE id = '$id'");
 
 if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
  echo '<p>error...</p>';
 }else{
  $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
  echo '<b>ok <b>';
  echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr>'
   <th>photo</th>
  </tr>';
  echo '<ul>';
  while($res = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $res->photo;?></td></tr>

Comment: Please provide formatted code

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the output, you are getting an image, but forgot to set the mime type in the header

header('Content-Type: image/png');

source :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

http://www.feedforall.com/mime-types.htm

Comment: I put, but didn't work. the php file doesn't show only image but also others values from database like int and varchar values...

Comment: you cannot put the image content image inline with the html code ( except if you are using data urls), you have got to load the image from separate script, and use an img tag with src to the image loading script.